# SSSD AD auth provider use tls port 636

Tags: linux, rhel, sssd

we are trying to use TLS port for AD communication for RedHat Linux 8 using sssd. after joining server to domain. using below sssd config for user authentication. I expect sssd to connect using port 636 to AD, but it still using the port 389.

**sssd.conf file**

```
[sssd]
domains = DEFAULT.COM
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/DEFAULT.COM]
dns_resolver_timeout = 15    .
ldap_network_timeout = 15
ad_domain = DEFAULT.COM
dyndns_update = false
krb5_realm = DEFAULT.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
ad_use_ldaps = True
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
ldap_service_port = 636
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = simple
debug_level = 9
```

Log show still using `389` port.

```
(2021-09-02 17:46:11): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0100): Marking port 389 of server '  as 'not working'
(2021-09-02 17:46:11): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0400): Marking port 389 of duplicate server   as 'not working'
(2021-09-02 17:46:11): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): Port status of port 389 for server   is 'neutral'
(2021-09-02 17:46:17): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0100): Marking port 389 of server   as 'not working'
(2021-09-02 17:46:17): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0400): Marking port 389 of duplicate server   as 'not working'
(2021-09-02 17:46:17): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): Port status of port 389 for server   is 'neutral'
(2021-09-02 17:46:23): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0100): Marking port 389 of server as 'not working'
(2021-09-02 17:46:23): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0400): Marking port 389 of duplicate server   as 'not working'
(2021-09-02 17:46:23): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): Port status of port 389 for server  is 'not working'
(2021-09-02 17:46:23): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): Port status of port 389 for server  is 'not working'
(2021-09-02 17:46:23): [be[DEFAULT.COM]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): Port status of port 389 for server  is 'not working'
```

How to force sssd to use secure port for communication.

Thanks
SR

Comment: I think that's the answer: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6565241 "The AD provider is a back end used to connect to an Active Directory server. This provider requires that the machine be joined to the AD domain and a keytab is available. When SSSD is configured in this way, back end communication occurs over a GSSAPI-encrypted channel, SSL/TLS options should not be used with the AD provider and will be superseded by Kerberos usage."